# MappedByteBuffer OOM caused by smaller buffer size?

Tags: java, jvm

I ran into an issue where I create `MappedByteBuffer`s of size 1KB, and slide through a file of size 20MB.

```
for(20MB file) {
    writeBuffer = fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, writeIndex, mappingSize);
    // write data into the writeBuffer 
    //update to new write index
}
```

In this case, I have created a whole bunch of 1KB `MappedByteBuffer`s, which I thought could be reused when moving forward in the file, which is clearly not the case here as I hit a OOM after sometime.

However, when I edit the mappingSize and make it 128KB for the same code above, the test runs fine (without an OOM).

Can someone explain how the buffer size of the `MappedByteBuffer` impact how the system allocates and reclaims resources (memory in this case)?

Comment: What version of jre? What OS? What is the exact exception and stack trace you get? Are you really just writing data to a file? Why use a memory map for that use rather than just writing directly to the file channel?

Comment: Using jdk1.7.0_04_x64 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64 Bit machine. It is a OOM "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
 at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:745)" Caused on adding a new MappedByteBuffer on 1KB. Well, technically we don't need a memory map (This was existing code I was looking at), but that said, I'm trying to find out why the buffer size makes a difference purely from a learning perspective :) Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that what is really changing based on different buffer size is how many loops you execute? Is there some other object you are allocating as you go through the loop that is not being dereferenced? Try forcing a heap dump on out of memory to analyze what is using all the memory. If it were actually the memory mapping, I would expect to see a message about direct byte buffer memory. Here are instructions for jvm args to force heap dump on out of memory: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: I would also note that is a pretty old version of jre (1.7.0_60 was released a couple of weeks ago). It may be worth taking latest version and working with that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @BrettOkken The number of loops are the same, and no i'm not allocating other objects. Let me try the forced heap dump. Thanks

Comment: So you changed the mapping size to 128KB but are still only processing 1KB at a time in your loop?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you hit [max_map_count](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt) limit. It is the maximum number of mappings a Linux process can create. This can be changed by root using `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=XXX`.

In Java unreferenced MappedByteBuffers and underlying file mappings are never released until the GC. But the GC is triggered only when you run out of Java Heap memory (disregarding the amount of native memory allocated). This means you can create many thousands of unreferenced MappedByteBuffers that will not be automatically freed. BTW, there is a hack to free them manually using non-public API:

```
    ((sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer) mappedByteBuffer).cleaner().clean();
```

Also, there is no sense in mapping 1K regions, because OS file mappings are always page-aligned, i.e. the start address and the size is always multiple of 4096 bytes.

*P.S.

There is a special case when Java forces GC on the failed `map()` in order to release memory occupied by unreferenced buffers. See [FileChannelImpl.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/bc7f9d966c1d/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/FileChannelImpl.java#l872). But if you disable explicit GC by JVM options for example, then you are in trouble.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no well-defined time at which the VM mapping underlying MappedByteBuffers can be released. So it is never released. So the fewer you use the better.